# Run executable from host within docker container

Tags: docker

I have a docker container and I would like to start a process in the host OS, and then have it execute in the context of the docker container. That is, my executable is a file in the host filesystem, and I want to start a process in the host OS, but I want to contain that process to the container, so that e.g. the process can only access the container's filesystem, etc.

For various reasons I do not want to copy the executable into the container and execute it there.

I do realize that this is a somewhat strange thing to be trying to do with docker containers!

Comment: how about mounting that directory to the container using `volume` and then executing the executables using `docker exec .. ` in the running container?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually trying to protect the external filesystem from begin accessed by the process running within the container so I that wouldn't work for me.

Comment: If you only care about filesystem, why not use `chroot`?

Comment: I'm concerned about security and was led to believe that chroot is not considered secure. Is that not so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mount the executable into the container with a volume like this:

```
$ docker run -v /path/to/executable:/my_exe debian /my_exe
```

The only problem is you will also need to take care of making sure any required libraries are also available in the container.